How can I use the Azure DevOps API to list deleted build definitions?
Azure DevOps supports restoration of deleted pipelines for up to 30 days. You can view deleted pipelines in the web UI at /_build/deleted by going here:

However, I can't find any way to list or otherwise get references to these deleted pipelines in the API. They are not included in the results returned by the Definitions - List or Pipelines - List endpoints, and I don't see an option to include them. The definitions resource supports a restore operation that requires knowing the ID of a deleted definition, but I don't see any way to find the IDs of deleted definitions in the first place.
If I use this trick (adding an undocumented querystring parameter to get a browser endpoint to return the JSON that populates the corresponding page) on /_build/deleted in the browser I can see the data I want in the response, so that's potentially an option, but trying to do that programmatically is painful because it looks like personal access tokens only work on the /_apis endpoints. I've made it work by using a Bearer token borrowed from the browser, but I don't want to go through the headache of getting a Bearer token programmatically too.

Sometimes the web-interface has more efficient APIs than what's available directly in the REST API. I was going to post the link to my blog post, but it looks like you already included it in the question.
You can call these endpoints with the __rt=fps&__ver=2.0 query parameters programmatically using a PAT token, just like you would normally do with any of the other REST API.
$organization = "<YOUR-ORGANIZATION>"
$project      = "<YOUR-PROJECT>"
$accessToken  = "<YOUR-PAT>"

$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_build/deleted?__rt=fps&__ver=2.0"
$uri = [Uri]::EscapeUriString($uri)

$header = @{ 
   Authorization = "Basic {0}" -f [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCI.GetBytes(":$($accessToken)"))
}

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $header -Method "GET"

The above approach works, but you'd have to parse the body of the response to find the data elements you need.
If you wanted to use the REST API, typically you would query the List endpoint and then query each pipeline (Get Definition) for a deletion status but it doesn't look like this data is currently exposed through the API.

Is a "Full access"-scope PAT required? I'm unable to create one of those in the org I'm in. I tried one with "Custom defined" scopes with everything selected and confirmed it works everywhere in the API, but I get 401s trying any of the web interface endpoints (which do work with a Bearer token).

@nlawalker, To list the build definitions, you need to have the following access: 1. Ensure your account can directly access the build definitions on Web UI of Azure DevOps, and have the permissions to restore deleted definitions if you want to restore any of the deleted ones.  2. If you want to list the build definitions using API, your PAT should have the 'Build (read)' (vso.build) scope at least.  3. If you want to restore the deleted build definitions using API, your PAT should have the 'Build (read and execute)' (vso.build_execute) scope at least.

@nlawalker, See "Scopes".

Thanks @BrightRan-MSFT, but I'm not trying to use the documented API endpoints, I'm trying to call /_build/deleted?__rt=fps, which is used by the UI. I am unable to create a PAT token that can access that endpoint, only a Bearer token appears to work.

@nlawalker I'm typically using the $(System.AccessToken) to invoke these API calls without issue. I'm assuming that PAT token is full-access.

@bryanbcook, No. The System.AccessToken does not have the full-access by default. Actually, it cannot access almost all the organization-level options.

@bryanbcook, if you want to use the System.AccessToken in pipeline to call pipelines related API, you might need to ensure the following two identities have the "View build pipeline" and "Edit build pipeline" permissions at least so that you can get/list and edit build pipelines.  - Project Collection Build Service ({OrganizationName})  - {Project Name} Build Service ({OrganizationName})

@bryanbcook, from here it looks like System.AccessToken is actually a Bearer token and not a PAT. For the record, I'm not working from within a pipeline at all, I'm in a standalone C# app. new DefaultAzureCredential().GetToken(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://management.core.windows.net//.default" }, null)).Token is working for my purposes.

@nlawalker & @bryanbcook, Yes, in pipeline you can directly use the System.AccessToken as Bearer token when calling REST API. You do not need to convert it to be Base64 token.
